# Image processing in Java like MATLAB Image Processing Toolbox

Tags: java, matlab, image-processing

Does it exist a solution for Java that allows to working with images in a very similar way to MATLAB IPT?
I mean, are there some libraries to do something like `IPT4Java.imfilter(A, F)` or `IPT4Java.fspecial('average', [3 3])`?

If not, what is the best solution to implement this kind of approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java Advanced Imaging (JAI) supports a multitude set of filters that you can apply on images.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at the Java wrapper around OpenCV:

http://code.google.com/p/javacv/